# Stripe IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I've got a Django website and I'm trying to integrate Stripe using Django the Stripe API on the backend and Vue.js on the frontend. However, when I try to run the checkout link that's supposed to redirect me to the payment processing page, I get the following error:

```
Error: IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.
    at new r (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:6143)
    at Js (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:165350)
    at $s (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:165646)
    at https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:166758
    at Qs (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:166769)
    at nc (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:167275)
    at Ec.redirectToCheckout (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:188030)
    at http://localhost:8000/dashboard/myaccount/teams/plans/:342:39
```

Here's the Vue.js method responsible for this:

```
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script>
        const PlansApp = {
            data() {
                return {

                }
            },
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            methods: {
                subscribe(plan) {
                    console.log('Subscribe:', plan);

                    const stripe = Stripe('{{ stripe_pub_key }}');

                    fetch('/dashboard/myaccount/teams/api/create_checkout_session/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            'plan': plan
                        })
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        return response.json()
                    })
                    .then(function(session) {
                        console.log(session)
                        return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.sessionId })
                    })
                    .then(function(result) {
                        if (result.error) {
                            console.log('Error:', result.error.message)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log('Error:', error);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        Vue.createApp(PlansApp).mount('#plans-app')
    </script>
```

And here's the Django code that creates the session on the backend:

```
@login_required
def create_checkout_session(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    plan = data['plan']

    if plan == 'basic':
        price_id = settings.STRIPE_BASIC_PRICE_ID
    else:
        price_id = settings.STRIPE_PRO_PRICE_ID

    try:
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            client_reference_id = request.user.userprofile.active_team_id,
            success_url = '%s%s?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}' % (settings.WEBSITE_URL, reverse('team:plans_thankyou')),
            cancel_url = '%s%s' % (settings.WEBSITE_URL, reverse('team:plans')),
            payment_method_types = ['card'],
            mode = 'subscription',
            line_items = [
                {
                    'price': price_id,
                    'quantity': 1
                }
            ]
        )
        return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})
```

I'm struggling to find out why I'm getting the error that I'm getting and would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I guest the problem come from the 'success_url' and the 'cancel_url'.

Try to add http:// or https:// in your url

Cordially